# SQL Server do not block table/row when I update row to the same value

Tags: sql-server, transaction

```sql
create table test  (
id int identity,
id_int int default 1
)

insert test default values
go 1000

begin transaction

update test 
set id_int = id_int
where id = 1000

waitfor delay  '00:00:10' 

commit
```

Another session without waiting get the result:

```sql
set transaction isolation  level read committed

select * from test 
where id =1000 


id    | id_int
---------------
1000  |1
```

Could someone explain why I get the result immediately?

However, when I use repeatable read isolation level I should wait:

```sql
set transaction isolation  level repeatable read

select * from test 
where id =1000
```

Comment: What is the database's `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting set to?

Comment: select is_read_committed_snapshot_on
from sys.databases
where name = 'AdventureWorks2016' returns 0 
(I am using SQL Server 2016)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is becauase SQL Server is doing a non updating update, look at the below locks it is aquiring in two cases,

**Case 1**: (Non updating update)

It is smart enough to allow `IS` lock while the `IX` is active on the obect.
[image]

**Case 2**: (Real update)

It waits for `IX` lock to be released before `IS` is granted to avoid dirty read.
[image]

**Case 3**: (Non updating update with serializable isolation)

If you want to explicity override this behavior you could use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation while doing the non udpating update which will get an `X` lock that blocks all other locks on it.
[image]

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN transaction

    update test 
    set id_int = id_int
    where id = 1000

    waitfor delay  '00:00:10' 

COMMIT
```